# How to use different sounds on one notification channel for an Android Foreground Service

Tags: android, audio, service, notifications, foreground

I have a foreground service that I set up a notification channel as required for Android API 26 and beyond, but I'm not able to dynamically set the sound for this notification.  Let me explain:

As the service starts, it creates an initial notification using startForeground as required of a foreground service.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to reuse this persistent notification that is already in the notification tray, updating the message to provide a visual status update.  This much I can already achieve.  In one particular case, I'd like to also update either the notification or notification channel to provide a new notification sound and display the notification to the user.  The notification always uses the same sound that was initially established when the service was first started and never becomes immediately visible to the user without sliding the notification tray down from the top of the screen.

What does seem to work is that I create a separate notification channel for this one case, but then I have two different notification items in the tray.  Another way that appears to work is shown on YouTube @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Je9ZEAAjfA where the author uses NotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel to remove, then NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel however, they said the OS will eventually delete my app if I keep re-creating the notification channel as some form of spam prevention.

Is there some way to reuse the original notification channel to dynamically change the sound and make it visible?

I'll go out on a limb and show the solution I chose.  The createNotificationChannels method gets called during onCreate, then createNotification gets called once at onStartCommand to satisfy the 5 second limit for calling startForeground.  Then I call createNotification, as needed, to select which of the 3 different channels to display and set the title/body contents.  I'd sure rather be able to dynamically set the sound.

```
private int CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_ID = 666;
public static final String TARGET_MESSAGING_GROUP_ID = "TargetMessagingGroupID";
public static final String TARGET_MESSAGING_GROUP_NAME = "Target Messaging Group";
public static final String WAITING_NEW_TARGET_CHANNEL_ID = "WaitingNewTargetChannelID";
public static final String WAITING_NEW_TARGET_CHANNEL_NAME = "Waiting for New Target Channel";
public static final String NAVIGATING_TO_TARGET_CHANNEL_ID = "NavigatingToTargetChannelID";
public static final String NAVIGATING_TO_TARGET_CHANNEL_NAME = "Navigating To Target Channel";
public static final String TARGET_ARRIVAL_CHANNEL_ID = "TargetArrivalChannelID";
public static final String TARGET_ARRIVAL_CHANNEL_NAME = "Target Arrival Channel";
    
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Method: createNotificationChannels
//
// Purpose: Called once at startup so we have the notification channels
//          ready to go when we need them
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
protected void createNotificationChannels()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        // use the same audio attributes for each channel
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION).build();

        // configure the group
        NotificationChannelGroup targetMessagingGroup = new NotificationChannelGroup(TARGET_MESSAGING_GROUP_ID, TARGET_MESSAGING_GROUP_NAME);

        // configure the first channel
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + parentContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.elevatording);
        NotificationChannel waitingNewTargetChannel = new NotificationChannel(WAITING_NEW_TARGET_CHANNEL_ID, WAITING_NEW_TARGET_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        waitingNewTargetChannel.setDescription(WAITING_NEW_TARGET_CHANNEL_NAME);
        waitingNewTargetChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        waitingNewTargetChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes); // This is IMPORTANT
        waitingNewTargetChannel.enableLights(true);
        waitingNewTargetChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        waitingNewTargetChannel.enableVibration(false);
        waitingNewTargetChannel.setGroup(TARGET_MESSAGING_GROUP_ID);

        // configure the second channel
        soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + parentContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.beep);
        NotificationChannel navigatingToTargetChannel = new NotificationChannel(NAVIGATING_TO_TARGET_CHANNEL_ID, NAVIGATING_TO_TARGET_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        navigatingToTargetChannel.setDescription(NAVIGATING_TO_TARGET_CHANNEL_NAME);
        navigatingToTargetChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        navigatingToTargetChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
        navigatingToTargetChannel.enableLights(false);
        navigatingToTargetChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        navigatingToTargetChannel.enableVibration(false);
        navigatingToTargetChannel.setGroup(TARGET_MESSAGING_GROUP_ID);

        // configure the third channel
        soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + parentContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.purge_siren_loud);
        NotificationChannel targetArrivalChannel = new NotificationChannel(TARGET_ARRIVAL_CHANNEL_ID, TARGET_ARRIVAL_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        targetArrivalChannel.setDescription(TARGET_ARRIVAL_CHANNEL_NAME);
        targetArrivalChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        targetArrivalChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes); // This is IMPORTANT
        targetArrivalChannel.enableLights(true);
        targetArrivalChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        targetArrivalChannel.enableVibration(true);
        targetArrivalChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        targetArrivalChannel.setGroup(TARGET_MESSAGING_GROUP_ID);

        // finally, register the group and associated channels with the OS
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(targetMessagingGroup);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(waitingNewTargetChannel);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(navigatingToTargetChannel);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(targetArrivalChannel);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Method: createNotification
//
// Purpose: Called whenever changing the displayed notification is
//          required.  Must call this with requestedNotificationType
//          of NOTIFY_TYPE_WAITING_FOR_TARGET from onStartCommand
//          in order to call startForeground within the 5 second limit
//          for a foreground service.
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
protected void createNotification(LocationService.LocationNotifyType requestedNotificationType, Bitmap notificationBitmap, Uri soundUri, String title, String message)
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(parentContext, signalledClass);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
    Notification notification = null;
    int notification_id = CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_ID;

    switch (requestedNotificationType)
    {
        default:
        {
            Log.d("LocationHandler", "Unknown LocationNotifyType, NOT changing notification");
            break;
        }
        case NOTIFY_TYPE_WAITING_FOR_TARGET:
        {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(parentContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(parentContext, WAITING_NEW_TARGET_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(notificationBitmap)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) // only affects API 25 and below
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setSummaryText("Waiting").setBigContentTitle(title).bigText(message))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker(getText(R.string.ticker_text))
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .build();

            if (notification != null)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                {
                    startForeground(notification_id, notification);
                }
                else
                {
                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(parentContext).notify(notification_id, notification);
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        case NOTIFY_TYPE_NAVIGATING:
        {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(parentContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(parentContext, NAVIGATING_TO_TARGET_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(notificationBitmap)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH) // only affects API 25 and below
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setSummaryText("Navigating").setBigContentTitle(title).bigText(message))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker(getText(R.string.ticker_text))
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .build();

            NotificationManagerCompat.from(parentContext).notify(notification_id, notification);
            break;
        }
        case NOTIFY_TYPE_ARRIVAL:
        {
            notificationIntent.setAction("ArrivalNotification");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
            notificationIntent.putExtra(AllConstants.APP_WAKEUP_TYPE, AllConstants.APP_WAKEUP_TARGET_ARRIVAL);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(parentContext, notification_id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(parentContext, TARGET_ARRIVAL_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(notificationBitmap)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) // only affects API 25 and below
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setSummaryText("Arrival").setBigContentTitle(title).bigText(message))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .build();

            NotificationManagerCompat.from(parentContext).notify(notification_id, notification);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Came to the conclusion that a Notification Group that consists of 3 specific notification channels each with it's own sound would achieve what I wanted to.  I use the same notification ID each time I want to replace the existing notification with a new one using NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(notification_id, notification);  with the exception of the first notification that must call startForeground(notification_id, notification);

Comment: But, still, if anyone has a better idea or can validate what I've learned, I would greatly appreciate feedback.